# Collapse issue in nunjucks template

Tags: html, nunjucks

I am using collapse in my Nunjucks template. At first, i want to show 100 characters when clicking on `more` it should expand(show total text continuously) but when I clicking on more the text is starting from new line instead of same line.

```
<p class="meta-info-decription" {{wikipedia.wiki_url}}>
    <span>
        {% if(wikipedia.wiki_extract.length > 100 ) %}
            {{ wikipedia.wiki_extract.slice(0,100) }}
            <span class="read-more more clickable"
                  data-toggle="collapse"
                  id="more-wiki-data"
                  data-target="#wiki-text">...more
            </span>
            <span id="wiki-text" class="collapse">
                {{ wikipedia.wiki_extract.slice(100)}}
                <span class="read-more less"
                      data-toggle="collapse"
                      id="more-wiki-data"
                      data-target="#wiki-text">less ...
                </span>
            </span>

        {% else %}
            {{ wikipedia.wiki_extract }}
        {% endif %}
    </span>
    <a href="{{ wikipedia.wiki_url }}" target="_blank">
        Wikipedia
    </a>
</p>
```

Before click on more:

[Before click on more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncZAe.png)

After Click on more:

[After click on more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI3c4.png)

Comment: Try `.wiki_extract.slice(0,100) -}}`.

Comment: Thanks, @Aikon Mogwai, But it's not working